# Prevent Mission Control from rearranging open applications/windows

Tags: macos, mission-control

Mission Control is automatically putting latest focused window/app on bottom right of Mission Control screen and that operation completely mixes arrangement of other open apps. Because of this I always spend ~5 seconds to find window that I am looking for and I am unable to memorize position of each app.

Is there any way to prevent Mission Control to rearrange apps based on last focused item?

This is a screenshot of the behavior I'm speaking about:
[image]

Comment: You mean in Exposé? Can you get a picture? I'm not seeing this behaviour. Also, what OS, what Mac, do you use fullscreen? https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eOTs.jpg

Comment: @Tetsujin here is screenshot of view that I am speaking about: https://postimg.cc/67XmTVBk I have MBP 2019 i7, macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: Maybe it's new in Catalina. All i can tell from that picture is you don't have 'Group by Application' set. The behaviour I see is that each mini-window moves as near as it can to where it last was, just enough to separate them all. Group by app will move all to the most recent front-most window's position.

Comment: I just tried it, but I have same behaviour since all running apps are different. @Tetsujin